# Facebook: FQL of Photo return Empty Array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I put this into the Graph Api Explorer:
fql?q=SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid='10150366114736999'

hoping to get some picture ID.

However, it's returning to me an empty array. I've all permissions checked, and I was able to see the photo itself if I put in a pid into the explorer, with the same Access Token.

Just what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query `select pid from photo where album_object_id=10150366114736999`.

See [my answer to "Facebook Graph API - get a photos album ID"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7898635/441108) for more information.